# ST_LineMerge to simplify road network

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I am trying to simplify my road network by finding all segments that touch 2 other lines with a common attribute, `join_id` and `street`, then doing a `st_linemerge`. I do NOT want to merge lines where there is a legitimate intersection. The end goal is to remove any unnecessary nodes in my road network.

**The red circles identify the line segments that should be merged into 1, resulting in 8 linestrings**:

[image]

**Sample data:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE edges_test (
    id integer,
    join_id character varying(15),
    street character varying(32),
    the_geom geometry(MultiLineString,4326)
);

INSERT INTO edges_test
(
    id, join_id, street, the_geom
)
VALUES
(152919,'5364001050000','HYLAN BOULEVARD',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.076549037205 40.6062177712225,-74.0765673473598 40.6061216642362))', 4326)),
(163162,'5364001050000','HYLAN BOULEVARD',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.0765673473598 40.6061216642362,-74.0765887729004 40.6060012862247))', 4326)),
(164278,'5154601070000','STATEN ISLAND EXPRESSWAY',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.0747578790902 40.6059918638443,-74.0748779616281 40.6060160205844,-74.0753290236186 40.6060929633246,-74.0754908197269 40.6061131335313))', 4326)),
(164279,'5154601070000','STATEN ISLAND EXPRESSWAY',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.0754908197269 40.6061131335313,-74.0758750018611 40.6061610259355,-74.0760098160418 40.606172376073,-74.0760455106313 40.6061753816192))', 4326)),
(164280,'5154601070000','STATEN ISLAND EXPRESSWAY',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.0760455106313 40.6061753816192,-74.076549037205 40.6062177712225))', 4326)),
(164284,'5154601060000','STATEN ISLAND EXPRESSWAY',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.0748137615045 40.6057770701806,-74.0752209528085 40.6058469663565,-74.0755409340908 40.6058951565944))', 4326)),
(164285,'5154601060000','STATEN ISLAND EXPRESSWAY',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.0755409340908 40.6058951565944,-74.0757990415962 40.6059340275554,-74.0758941551205 40.6059421283636,-74.0760898820693 40.6059587982079))', 4326)),
(164286,'5154601060000','STATEN ISLAND EXPRESSWAY',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.0760898820693 40.6059587982079,-74.0765887729004 40.6060012862247))', 4326)),
(166736,'5364001050000','HYLAN BOULEVARD',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.0765017287402 40.606466130529,-74.0765330374503 40.6063017649758))', 4326)),
(166737,'5364001050000','HYLAN BOULEVARD',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.0765330374503 40.6063017649758,-74.076549037205 40.6062177712225))', 4326)),
(166738,'5209101000000','STATEN ISLAND EXPWY ET 13 B WB',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.076549037205 40.6062177712225,-74.0770963146923 40.6063461215705))', 4326)),
(166740,'5154601070000','STATEN ISLAND EXPRESSWAY',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.076549037205 40.6062177712225,-74.077116909924 40.6062540917328))', 4326)),
(166742,'5154601060000','STATEN ISLAND EXPRESSWAY',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.0765887729004 40.6060012862247,-74.0771604232288 40.6060339913006,-74.0771785369999 40.6060348585715))', 4326)),
(166851,'5364001050000','HYLAN BOULEVARD',ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING((-74.0765887729004 40.6060012862247,-74.0766012139353 40.6059313624662))', 4326))
;
```

**My (very) wrong query:**

```sql
SELECT 
e1.join_id, -- identifier for same street segment
e1.street, 
ST_LineMerge(St_union(e1.the_geom)) as the_geom,
    COUNT(*)
    INTO edges_output
FROM edges_test e1
JOIN edges_test e2 ON ST_Touches(e1.the_geom, e2.the_geom)
    GROUP BY
    e1.join_id,
    e1.street
    HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: an `UPDATE` will not remove rows, it updates [sic!] existing rows; you'll need to either create a new table (do), or delete obsolete records (don't, in-table geometry record merges are somewhat of an anti-pattern).

Comment: @ThingumaBob thanks, I have updated the SQL. Im still not sure why most of my segments are being joined together at intersecting (3+) lines.

Comment: Please put sample data for a failing case

Comment: @JGH i have updated my post with sample data and attempted to clarify the issue a little bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

would something like this do the job?

**UPDATE1**: used st_crosses instead of st_intersects and not st_equals and created an index for the geometry

**UPDATE2**: instead of calculating a huge multipoint, lets calculate one multipoint per join_id and let's split only the line with this join_id. Also, if a particular join_id has only one segment bring it anyways

**UPDATE3**: update2 had a bug -- this fixes it. morespecifically it didn't take into account that some lines would touch instead of cross.

```
 WITH edges_test_merged as (SELECT join_id, 
                street,
                ST_LineMerge(ST_Union(f.the_geom)) as singlegeom
            FROM edges_test As f
            GROUP BY 1,2
    ),

 edges_intersections as( SELECT a.join_id, a.street, st_union(st_intersection(a.singlegeom, b.singlegeom)) as geom
                FROM edges_test_merged a
                JOIN edges_test_merged b
                ON ST_crosses(a.singlegeom, b.singlegeom) or st_touches(a.singlegeom, b.singlegeom)
                group by 1,2)

SELECT l.join_id as ljoinid, l.street as lstreet
    ,(st_dump(st_split(l.singlegeom, p.geom))).geom
FROM edges_test_merged as l
JOIN edges_intersections as p
ON l.join_id = p.join_id
```

In addition you can index your geometry column (don't know if you already have) by

```
CREATE INDEX edges_test_geom_idx ON edges_test USING GIST (the_geom);
```

Query cost before:

```
Result  (cost=21024.52..21348.80 rows=1000 width=162) (actual time=1.481..1.673 rows=8 loops=1)
```

Query cost after update1:

```
Result  (cost=55.32..327.05 rows=1000 width=162) (actual time=1.297..1.436 rows=8 loops=1)
```

Query cost after update2:

```
Result  (cost=55.36..3804.30 rows=14000 width=162) (actual time=1.773..1.821 rows=8 loops=1)
```

Query cost after update3:

```
Result  (cost=104.35..372.45 rows=1000 width=162) (actual time=2.121..2.160 rows=8 loops=1)
```

probably there is a better way to do this. I am curious at to how this will perform on a large dataset.

Comment: This works well on the sample data but unfortunately it is too slow to run on larger data sets. Is there any way it can be optimized?

Comment: hi, updated my answer above. please take a look

Comment: Thanks, on both the original and new queries I am getting `ERROR:  Splitting a Line by a GeometryCollection is unsupported` when running on a larger dataset. (~150k rows)

Comment: this is interesting. i'll do some digging and will come back to you

Comment: it won't have the desired result, because each line has to be split *at the same time* by all points which intersect it, rather than first by point A, then by point B etc which will results in multiple (overlapping) line segments

Comment: ok, give it another go! and let's cross fingers :)

Comment: hi its30, update3 and hopefully final. could you confirm that everything is ok?

Comment: @vagvaf I am running the query now, it is still running quite slow for some reason. I will check back in later with results, thanks.

Comment: Also to add, i do have an index on my source data geometry `edges_test` per the example.

Comment: That works! It takes about 1hr 30min to run on my data but i suppose thats about the best I can hope for. Thanks for the help.