# Trouble updating field calculatd by st_ functions

Tags: postgis, update, null, boolean

I had first run this code on several of my fields of my T1 table at the same time.

```
UPDATE table_1
SET field_1 = liste.my_bool
FROM(
    SELECT T1.id AS name,
    bool_or((ST_Contains(T2.geom, T1.geom) OR ST_Overlaps(T1.geom,T2.geom))) AS my_bool
    FROM table_1 AS T1
    CROSS JOIN table_2 AS T2
    GROUP BY T1.id
 ) AS liste
WHERE table_1.id = liste.name;
```

But some fields as `field_1` were returning a null value. This is due to the fact that `table_2` was empty.
I need to make additional operations on these fields and I want to be `False` instead of `null`.
Therefore I went with these lines of code:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET field_1 = CASE WHEN liste.my_bool IS NOT NULL THEN liste.my_bool ELSE False END
FROM(
    SELECT T1.id AS name,
    bool_or((ST_Contains(T2.geom, T1.geom) OR ST_Overlaps(T1.geom,T2.geom))) AS my_bool
    FROM table_1 AS T1
    CROSS JOIN table_2 AS T2
    GROUP BY T1.id
     ) AS liste
WHERE table_1.id = liste.name
```

but nothing changed. I do not understand why, how can I correct my fields and avoid `null` values ?

**UPDATE 1:** here some data from my table_1, table_2 is empty and contains no row.
The geometry is in 2154 and describes polygons.

```
id, geom, field_1
(110853, '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', NULL)
(111016, '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', NULL)
(111018, '01060000206A080000010000000103000000010000001600000076A911FAD7812B41E2AC889DF0815941205D6CFAD7812B41CE35CC2BF1815941F581E4DDC1812B41292158D4F6815941E8A4F74DB0812B41DE5850E5FB81594126C63275AE812B41F5691526228259417C0C561CE5812B41802903302C82594116DF50C004822B41E013EBF52E82594194DC61E3A6822B412D944C2C328259411B63276C4D832B41958103CB34825941AAF3A8A80A842B41D107CB17398259415E2EE2AB1C842B41F030ED153982594190F469ED32842B41EF1B5FD13682594128B7ED4B5F842B41BDFC4EE42E8259412A5778F78B842B41C6A700C6298259419065C1E4CE842B41130F28632282594186AE440809852B41D731AE281C8259412A57787F50852B41A3AD4AE715825941C440D786AE852B41C9E8800C0F825941408523D052852B41058BC3F5F6815941C843DFBDC1822B41689599CBEF815941AED51EA6BD822B417558E1DCF481594176A911FAD7812B41E2AC889DF0815941', NULL)
(111020, '01060000206A0800000100000001030000000100000008000000B5E04567FA5E2B413DBB7C95FA7F59413332C8A5AE602B41D07D39562180594163635E6716612B41802BD95E0B805941AB5AD2C11C612B41711E4EC8FE7F594166A19DF35D612B416F2D9312E47F5941EA25C65A3A602B4166498087C87F59412104E47BFA5E2B4131975447FA7F5941B5E04567FA5E2B413DBB7C95FA7F5941', NULL)
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
(111041, '01060000206A0800000100000001030000000100000009000000DB4C8560D0872B41363FFEFCF3815941AD31E8942B872B41FD2FD703FA815941185A9D7C8F862B41F853E3B0038259418B34F18631852B41F29716F81C82594184B9DD9B18862B415AF10D183E82594120B3B3A8C5862B411EDFDE603482594195F430ECC1872B41BB5E9A7B558259412F6B625175882B41E1F1EDFA2B825941DB4C8560D0872B41363FFEFCF3815941', NULL)
(119661, '01060000206A0800000100000001030000000100000004000000A8ABD0CE42892841FB2A6C34CFCC59411C81B3A98C89284197181DCED0CC5941139A24A6888928419B03047BCDCC5941A8ABD0CE42892841FB2A6C34CFCC5941', NULL)
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
(120114, '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', NULL)
(120116, '01060000206A080000010000000103000000010000000900000016A24398B8482E419BAE2748B3B159414B3E76EF51482E41FA4674EBC5B159411822A7D7F7482E41354069EBE2B15941C53A554EB7492E4126A60BEBD4B15941C520B08267492E416D718DCCC6B15941C03FA5127A492E41529D0E0CC2B15941944BE33F80492E4109C03F40C1B15941F4C308B927492E41C9C7EECFBDB1594116A24398B8482E419BAE2748B3B15941', NULL)
(120117, '01060000206A0800000100000001030000000100000009000000306821790D692E41BD1DE1728DA75941CFF92916C1682E41B4C9E1E98AA7594185B01A6387682E41BAF3C4EF9EA75941B709F76A70682E41EAB46E97B1A7594119CBF4CBCE682E41DF701F78BBA75941035DFB3A3A692E4144FCC3EABAA759417D5BB04C73692E4103EACDAF9EA759415D177EB875692E414EF04D5A90A75941306821790D692E41BD1DE1728DA75941', NULL)
(120118, '01060000206A0800000100000001030000000100000011000000BFB8544D781D2E41994A3F3C9AAD5941B3B11213211E2E41213F1BF0A8AD5941D9EBDD6F541E2E414BE5ED30A7AD5941A051BADCBA1E2E41219221B2A3AD594112DC48E1291F2E41C11F7E41A3AD59415133A46A651F2E410D1824DEA4AD59411BD65486AE1F2E41E690D472A4AD594145D8F09C38202E4155A18157A6AD5941C91CCB9B71202E41B189CC4CA8AD59414BE7C3EBBE202E413BFC350098AD5941E92ADDDDAB202E411286015496AD59417F677BDCBB202E416B7D914194AD5941348463C6101F2E41D271358D71AD5941D89AADA4731F2E41DD239B2F5FAD59414FCAA4E6141F2E41B0A9F34E60AD59418E1EBF1F8B1E2E41F984EC7961AD5941BFB8544D781D2E41994A3F3C9AAD5941', NULL)
(120119, '01060000206A080000010000000103000000010000000D000000B1C22D1F78472E410917F212A4AD594128637CF849472E41075E2D73B7AD59411BA19FA97D482E4194F8DC5AC0AD59412E20B4AE3F492E41A0FCDD4AD2AD59418AC74545D1492E41D89AADE3D6AD5941A52E190F3D4A2E41C5758CAABEAD594168226C20E0492E414EB9C2B3BCAD5941970167C96F492E4100ADF98EB6AD59416D57E86BC6482E4104745FFBB1AD5941E8DB825D3E482E413EB48F78ACAD5941397F13F2C1472E41508D9763A3AD5941B9196ED87C472E4122AB5B28A3AD5941B1C22D1F78472E410917F212A4AD5941', NULL)
(120121, '01060000206A080000010000000103000000010000000D000000B22D039E955C2E41BEF5610AEC9D59410470B358035D2E411D908454EA9D59412ECA6C38815D2E4180441375DC9D5941732CEF429A5D2E4177DB8522D79D5941378B1793935D2E419FE6E431B39D5941378E586B1B5D2E41BBEEADFA999D5941EA9271CC255C2E41B24B546C949D59413B8E1F8A685B2E41F3734360A29D5941DCA0F6BB3F5B2E412B8A579EB89D5941252026D9455B2E413E416204D39D59417D3F356EBD5B2E4164ADA1CDE39D5941D0251C021F5C2E4135626686E99D5941B22D039E955C2E41BEF5610AEC9D5941', NULL)
(120164, '01060000206A0800000100000001030000000100000009000000AD35941A06C12B41C7A013506E1B5941DE205A5BF3C12B41E179A9B9781B5941D595CFDA7DC22B41D05FE891511B5941C4211B58F9C12B41F8FBC51B421B5941FF04176B83C12B41438EAD59461B59417BC03C5C28C12B4158A83567541B5941F94B8B4222C12B416B2920C4591B5941E869C08026C12B41096F0F89681B5941AD35941A06C12B41C7A013506E1B5941', NULL)
(120182, '01060000206A080000010000000103000000010000000B0000007CB60EB638412C417A54FC11C1885941C07B47250B412C4119C8B337C5885941B3EA736DC3402C41E886A653CE8859414BE999DE95402C41B4AB90F2D4885941B340BBFB40402C41067FBF9ADB8859413A77BB3606402C4177F69569E1885941B5368D8DCB3F2C41122F4FDCE8885941FF3EE342F5402C418CA207F30689594136053283C6412C4177D66E19F78859410F26C5E759412C4168B3EA4FC48859417CB60EB638412C417A54FC11C1885941', NULL)
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
(121257, '01060000206A0800000100000001030000000100000005000000A1681E40ADA026416E6B0B4A04C35941A6B8AA6C73A22641C2A222CD19C3594175779DB5AFA22641D506270504C35941B56B4212D7A02641EA5E2713EDC25941A1681E40ADA026416E6B0B4A04C35941', NULL)
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
```

**UPDATE 2:** I have tried to change my `field_1` with this query and it remained `null`. I do not understand why this simple query doesn't impact the field.

```
UPDATE table_1
SET field_1= 
    CASE WHEN field_1 IS NULL THEN FALSE END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no issue with your second query. It returns true or false for features that are in the second table. But as your second table is empty the result from your inner select query is empty. So when you use where condition `WHERE table_1.id = liste.name;` no feature is updated. Instead, you should have a condition like `WHERE table_1.id = liste.name or table_1.field_1 is null;` So your Final Query would be something like

```
UPDATE table_1
SET field_1 = CASE WHEN liste.my_bool IS NOT NULL THEN liste.my_bool ELSE False END
FROM(
    SELECT T1.id AS name,
    bool_or((ST_Contains(T2.geom, T1.geom) OR ST_Overlaps(T1.geom,T2.geom))) AS my_bool
    FROM table_1 AS T1
    CROSS JOIN table_2 AS T2
    GROUP BY T1.id
     ) AS liste
WHERE table_1.id = liste.name or table_1.field_1 is null;
```

Comment: my filed_1 from my table_1 is still null after this querry.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE1: although why you want to do this escapes me (joining with empty table) this query probably does what you want.

```
    WITH empty as (SELECT T1.id AS name,
                          bool_or((ST_Contains(T2.geom, T1.geom) OR ST_Overlaps(T1.geom,T2.geom))) AS my_bool
                   FROM table_1 AS T1
                   CROSS JOIN table_2 AS T2
                   GROUP BY T1.id
                  )

    UPDATE table_1
    SET field_1 = coalesce(liste.my_bool,False)
    FROM (
         SELECT table_1.id, empty.name, empty.my_bool
         FROM empty
         RIGHT JOIN table_1
         on table_1.id = empty.name
        ) as liste
    WHERE table_1.id = liste.id
```

Comment: My field is still full of "null" values. The code does not change the values. This is something I had guessed previously. I cannot change the value of field_1 by the querry anymore...

Comment: You are right, that's because the NULL value is not returned by the bool_or function. Unfortunately I will be away for the next day's from a PC and without some sample data from the two tables it's difficult to suggest a solution

Comment: Ok, how can give you some data ?

Comment: Check this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326433/st-linemerge-to-simplify-road-network/327740#327740 try to include data that cover all the cases from both tables. Also post them on the main question to help others that may want to pick it up.

Comment: hi, i have updated my answer

Comment: I decided to leave the fields_1 as is, and change it through a second querry. Thanks for the help.